# Pygame.draw.arc() completion bug or just me?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame, draw

I'm trying to draw several arc with squares at the end points and I have most of it but something is not quite right with the end points. there's always a few pixels gap between where I think the arc should end and where it is drawn. Example code below:

```
import pygame
from math import pi

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([1000,1000])
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
done = False

while not done:
    clock.tick(10)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
    screen.fill((0,0,0))

    # draw first arc just past pi/2 to make sure arc is not cut off by rectangle bounds
    pygame.draw.arc(screen, (255,255,255),[100,100,800,800], 0, 9 * pi / 16, 1)

    # normal, easy, simple, arc does not touch vertical red line as expected
    pygame.draw.arc(screen, (255,255,255),[200,200,600,600], 0, 2 * pi, 1)

    # shorter arc because in my actual code it seems that smaller arcs have larger gaps
    # but I can't seem to tell here besides it doesn't connect either
    pygame.draw.arc(screen, (255,255,255),[300,300,400,400], 4 * pi / 16, pi / 2, 1)

    # Horizontal and vertical lines for comparison
    pygame.draw.line(screen, (255,0,0), [500,500], [500,0])
    pygame.draw.line(screen, (255,0,0), [500,500], [900,500])

    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

[Sample output][1] Notice the gaps just to the left of the mouse cursor. https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zxkG.jpg

Same results on  OS X and Linux Mint. Drawing the lines first doesn't make a difference and it's always the end points not the starting points. Thanks for reading!

Comment: Looking at the API, the `arc` function takes a start angle and a stop angle, but it looks like you've only specified one of the two. Could that be the issue?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. I've edited the code to add the start points at 0 as they should have been. Except for the last arc which goes from pi/4 to pi/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved thanks to /u/Mekire in [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/pygame/comments/2o5vb4/does_anyone_here_have_any_ideas_on_this_arc/)

```
import pygame
from pygame import gfxdraw

RED = pygame.Color("red")
WHITE = pygame.Color("white")

def draw_arc(surface, center, radius, start_angle, stop_angle, color):
    x,y = center
    start_angle = int(start_angle%360)
    stop_angle = int(stop_angle%360)
    if start_angle == stop_angle:
        gfxdraw.circle(surface, x, y, radius, color)
    else:
        gfxdraw.arc(surface, x, y, radius, start_angle, stop_angle, color)


pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([500,500])
screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
x,y = screen_rect.center
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
done = False

while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    #Arcs
    draw_arc(screen, screen_rect.center, 200, 45, 360, WHITE)
    draw_arc(screen, screen_rect.center, 220, 0, 360, WHITE)
    draw_arc(screen, screen_rect.center, 100, -90, -135, WHITE)
    draw_arc(screen, screen_rect.center, 120, -135, -90, WHITE)
    # Horizontal and vertical lines for comparison
    pygame.draw.line(screen, RED, screen_rect.center, screen_rect.midright)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, RED, screen_rect.center, screen_rect.midtop)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, RED, screen_rect.topleft, screen_rect.bottomright)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(30)

pygame.quit()
```